# DNS resolvers speed test? What is my current DNS resolver?

Tags: server, dns

1. Will switching to CloudFlare  DNS resolver 1.1.1.1 speed things up for me?
   Is there a way to test for this?
2. What is my current DNS resolver is: is it 127.0.0.53 (Ubuntu)  or 198.105.244.23 (Century Link which is my current ISP)?

In trying to answer these 2 questions I ran the following to scripts:

When I ran this courtesy of https://github.com/cleanbrowsing/dnsperftest:

These are the results:

```
:~/dnsperftest$ bash ./dnstest.sh sort -k 22 -n

              test1   test2   test3   test4   test5   test6   test7   test8   test9   test10  Average 

127.0.0.53        28 ms   23 ms   24 ms   23 ms   24 ms   25 ms   24 ms   24 ms   1 ms    103 ms    29.90
cloudflare        23 ms   24 ms   23 ms   23 ms   23 ms   23 ms   23 ms   24 ms   23 ms   40 ms     24.90
level3            66 ms   73 ms   72 ms   71 ms   74 ms   74 ms   70 ms   71 ms   73 ms   73 ms     71.70
google            23 ms   23 ms   22 ms   108 ms  70 ms   175 ms  23 ms   117 ms  22 ms   155 ms    73.80
quad9             133 ms  74 ms   71 ms   73 ms   75 ms   74 ms   74 ms   71 ms   73 ms   74 ms     79.20
freenom           65 ms   73 ms   73 ms   73 ms   175 ms  177 ms  176 ms  175 ms  73 ms   176 ms    123.60
opendns           65 ms   23 ms   22 ms   23 ms   23 ms   151 ms  23 ms   119 ms  22 ms   23 ms     49.40
norton            156 ms  72 ms   68 ms   152 ms  153 ms  74 ms   72 ms   75 ms   71 ms   73 ms     96.60
cleanbrowsing     24 ms   25 ms   25 ms   23 ms   24 ms   25 ms   24 ms   23 ms   24 ms   27 ms     24.40
yandex            209 ms  278 ms  277 ms  277 ms  278 ms  283 ms  272 ms  270 ms  372 ms  380 ms    289.60
adguard           166 ms  174 ms  177 ms  174 ms  162 ms  177 ms  177 ms  173 ms  170 ms  156 ms    170.60
neustar           23 ms   23 ms   22 ms   23 ms   25 ms   22 ms   23 ms   22 ms   24 ms   36 ms     24.30
comodo            24 ms   24 ms   23 ms   24 ms   25 ms   24 ms   24 ms   23 ms   23 ms   24 ms     23.80
```

I googled the first DNS server and found this definition on AskUbuntu:

127.0.0.53 is the address of the local caching stub resolver. It forwards DNS requests to whatever upstream DNS servers you specify.

I was like "Great, no need to change my DNS is already running at top speed"

But when I ran this:

```
 $ systemd-resolve protocol
protocol: 198.105.244.23
          198.105.254.23
          (protocol.Home)

-- Information acquired via protocol DNS in 150.9ms.
-- Data is authenticated: no
```

When I google these last 2 DNS numbers, Akamai technologies which is connected to Century Link my ISP comes up.

Can somebody explain in plain language what is gong on?

Why the differnt DNS servers #s?
Why the huge speed difference?
Finally should I switch to CloudFlare or some other DNS in the table or just stick to what I have?

Thank You

Comment: I don't understand the question .. plus/minus a ms indns-lookups doesn't make a difference. You only do dns-lookup once when you setup a new session.

Comment: @ Soren A. Per your comment I attempted to clarify the question in the main entry of my submission. Agreed on the ms indifference. But I am curious as to way when I ran $ systemd-resolve protocol it took 150.9ms. versus the average 23ms of cloudflare in  :~/dnsperftest$ bash ./dnstest.sh sort -k 22 -n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### First things first:

*systemd-resolved* (with the 'd' ) is a service which is your DNS client on your local machine. 
*systemd-resolve* (without 'd' ) is an app that can be used for interfacing with the DNS client.

You can check your currently configured DNS servers with:

```
systemd-resolve --status
or
resolvectl status
or
cat /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
```

127.0.0.53 is your loopback IP which is bounded to your local DNS client.
The file */etc/resolve.conf* is symlinked to */run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf*
which holds this IP. Its purpose is to point applications, which would try to get directly to DNS server, back to the systemd-resolved DNS client.

The command you used, "systemd-resolve protocol" - is attempting to complete the domain with *.home* and resolve *protocol.home* - I am not sure how did it work, perhaps you are directly connected to the provider's network and you were able to reach provider's DNS via LLMNR

#### So how it works

When you are querying for the domain:

1. DNS client is checking */etc/hosts* for static entries
2. DNS client is checking its cache
3. DNS client is contacting upstream DNS server configured in /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf
4. DNS server is checking its cache and if the domain is there, it will reply with IP address
5. If the DNS server doesn't have this domain stored in the cache, it will perform recursive lookup before returning to your client with the answer.

As you can imagine, there will be significant difference in latency depending on at which stage you will get the address resolution.
The latency will also depend on the current load of the DNS server.

#### Should you switch to Cloudflare DNS?

Perceived DNS server performance depends on two factors:

1. How far is the server (IP latency)
2. How fast can it process your query (is answer cached, is the server overloaded etc)

Cloudflare is claiming to provide safe and secure service. From all my tests it performs better than local ISPs and google's DNS servers. But the tests may have different results depending on location.

You are not loosing anything by switching to different reputable DNS service so you should check the experience for yourself.

What I would recommend is to have at least local caching DNS server (such as one in the router).

Personally I have noticed significant experience improvement, since I have setup my personal recursive DNS server.